# What is the difference between these regex expressions - perl

Tags: perl

I have a line of text in a file image1.hd

```
axial rotation:=0.880157
```

I want the number. Using core perl I do this

```
open FILE, "<", "$Z_DIR/image1.hd" or die $!;
  while (<FILE>){
    if (/axial rotation:=(\S+)/)
      {
    $axial_rot = $1;
      }
  }
  close FILE;
```

which returns the desired output of =0.880157

I would prefer a one liner as I will do similar to a few other files. Earlier I learned of the module File::Slurp and I tried the following with positive look behind assertion

```
my $axial_rot = read_file("$Z_DIR/image1.hd") =~ /(?<=axial rotation:=)\S+/
```

This returns 1 - regardless of the regex. How can I alter the latter regex to achieve the desired output

Comment: Why slurp the file unless you have to? Is your axial rotation line a multi-line statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using the assignment in scalar context, which makes the match return the number of matches. By switching to list context, you can use a matching group to return the needed substring:

```
my ($axial_rot) = read_file("$Z_DIR/image1.hd") =~ /axial rotation:=(\S+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't read in an entire file into memory unless you need to.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

sub find_in_file{
  my($filename,$regex) = @_;
  my @return;

  open my $fh, '<', $filename; # or die handled by autodie

  while( my $line = <$fh> ){
    last if (@return) = $line =~ $regex
  }

  close $fh; # or die handled by autodie

  return $return[0] unless wantarray;
  return @return;
}

my $Z_DIR = '.';
my $axial_rot = find_in_file( "$Z_DIR/image1.hd", qr'\baxial rotation:=(\S+)' );
```